# Residual-current device: Would a big coil trigger it because it stores electrons?

Tags: rcd

Imagine a residual-current device at your home - basically it counts influx of electrons vs outflux of electrons. If there is a missmatch (e.g. I=30mA over t=30ms), it triggers and disables the circuit.

What if I connect a big coil? Because of the inductance it would store a certain amount of charge which is released later on when it is disconnected from the voltage source.

Would the missing amount of charge be able to trigger a RCD? Because the RCD would see only some charge flowing into the coil but not coming out again right after connecting the coil?

What would happen if I connected a big capacitance?

Comment: This is where the 'water-pipe' analogy of current flow breaks. It doesn't work that way. In order for charge to be stored in an inductor or capacitor, current must flow through the entire circuit, not just 'in' to the device.

Comment: In other words, inductors and capacitors don't store electrons, they store energy in the form of magnetic or electric fields, respectively.

Comment: You probably need to think about simpler circuits than this. Your terminology is quite poor, and this shows your understanding is probably quite limited. Look into how a RCD can be triggered for testing (with a resistor), and also consider how a motor can be attached to an RCD protected circuit.

Comment: Sorry for the poor terminology, that is more related to English not being my mother's tongue. I forgot about the fact that energy is stored in form of fields, not in actual charge. Thanks for clearing that up. I had a hard time to decide between transistor and @mkeith, in the end I gave the later one the acknowledgement, although both had a good explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circuit elements such as batteries and capacitors inductors, resistors, motors diodes etc do not store charge in the sense you are thinking of. Often, when we are writing or speaking casually we talk about capacitors "storing" charge. This is very confusing to beginners, and I remember being confused about it at some point during my education. I didn't understand how we could use Kirchoff's current law on reactive circuits. A professor clarified the point for me.

When analyzing circuits, for every charge that flows into a capacitor (or any other circuit element), another charge flows out of the opposite terminal. So the net charge is unchanged. **Circuit elements do not accumulate charge.** If they did, we would not be able to use Kirchoff's Current Law to analyze circuits.

Capacitors separate charges, and this separation gives rise to an electric field. Also, this separation is a form of potential energy that can be used to do work. But it is not a form of charge storage in the sense you are thinking about.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I connect a big coil? Because of the inductance it would store a certain amount of charge which is released later on when it is disconnected from the voltage source.

If you disconnect a "charged" inductor it will arc at the relay contacts to "discharge". It obeys normal circuit rules.

> Would the missing amount of charge be able to trigger a RCD? Because the RCD would see only some charge flowing into the coil but not coming out again right after connecting the coil?

Current is like water in a closed loop pumping system. You can't have current in without current out. The inductor doesn't store current - it stores magnetic energy.

> What would happen if I connected a big capacitance?

This time the energy would be stored in an electric field. Current in = current out.